# Como fazer uma estrutura com divs do mesmo id

Tags: html, css

Bom, ultimamente tenho visto em muitos templates, que uma div com um mesmo id, toma lugares no espaço diferentes. Eu como tenho poucos conhecimentos de CSS, pretendia fazer algo que se assemelhe a isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, uma div com um mesmo id toma 4 lugares em cima, e no "5º" lugar, passa automaticamente para baixo e a estrutura repete-se assim atá haver divs...

Como poderei fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer que a 5ª div passe para baixo quando diminuir a tela?

Comment: Não, a tela fica sempre igual mas por exemplo escrevo 5 divs com o mesmo id no codigo e a quinta passa automaticamente para baixo, tal como demonstrei no exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, um `ID` tem esse nome por que significa que é uma referência única, para criar um identificador para todas as suas `div`s, você deve utilizar uma `classe`, um exemplo referente ao que você solicitou poderia ser feito da seguinte forma:

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.float {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 1% 0;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
    <div class="float">  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta isto mesmo que eu precisava! Já agora, sabe-me dizer qual é que foi a "condição" para que ficassem 4 em cada linha?

Comment: o `float: left` faz com que elas se alinhem lado a lado enquanto couber dentro de onde elas estiverem, no caso, a `div#container`, e o tamanho delas (`width: 20%`) determina quantas irão caber, nessa conta seriam 5, porém como eu coloquei uma margem entre elas só cabem 4...

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente ajuda!

Comment: Imagine, considere marcar a resposta como correta para futuros visitantes do post, por gentileza! :)

Comment: Já coloquei !!!